# Inserting array into array with mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having issues inserting nested arrays with Mongoose.
[image: Database Schema]

I am trying to insert an AP into the APList array inside the specific network inside the networks array.

I have been trying to use:

```
var ap = {
    MAC      : req.body.APMAC,
    location : req.body.location
}
var query = {
    name            : req.decoded.name,
    'networks.ssid' : req.body.ssid
}

User.update(query, 
            {$push: {'APList' : ap}},
            {safe: true, upsert: true, new: true},
            function(err, data) {
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: "Added AP"
                })
            })
```

`req.decoded.name` comes from a JWT and the body parameters sent are APMAC, location & ssid.

This always lands with a success "Added AP" message, but hasn't updated the APList array to include the AP sent in the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator together with the **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** in your update to add the `ap` object to the embedded `APList` field.

The **[`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** will identify for you the correct element in the `networks` array to update without explicitly specifying its position in the array, thus your final update statement should look like:

```
User.update(query,
    { "$push": { "networks.$.APList": ap } },
    { "upsert": true, "new": true },
    function(err, data) {
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: "Added AP",
            data: data
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still hasn't worked. The data I get back reads: `{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Added AP",
  "data": {
    "ok": 0,
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0
  }
}`

Comment: Check you query, test using some sample documents with mongo shell as debugging hints.